# Permission denied reading from sdcard

Tags: android

I test my application on a virtual nexus 5 with Marshmallow

I got a notification about a virtual sd card being ready and I tried choosing both internal and external storage.

I uploaded a text file to sdcard/Download by dragging and dropping to the emulator.

I added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` and even `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` to my manifest.

When I try to read a file a sd card using code such as this

```
 File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

 File file = new File(sdcard,"Download/gradle.build");

 try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))
 ...}
```

I get an open failed... EACCESS - permission denied exception thrown.

Why can't I read a file from the sdcard? Thanks.

Comment: *If the device is running Android 6.0 or higher, and your app's target SDK is 23 or higher: The app has to list the permissions in the manifest, **and** it must request each dangerous permission it needs while the app is running* https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Request permission at runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) is a feature added in android version 6.0 The idea is when the app is installed customers just grant permission without knowing the security risk. Dangerous permission must be granted at runtime so hopefully users know the risk, in this case you want to use SD storage because (give reason here). Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are targetting devices marshmallow or above you have to give permissions at runtime and permissions declared in manifest does not mean anything. So have to give permission like below before accessing any of the file related read or write.

first check if permission already given by checking this

```
       // Assume this Activity is the current activity
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (permissionCheck==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
         //this means permission is granted and you can do read and write
        }else{
         requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION);
        }
```

here is permission [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)